# Subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is countable iff it contains no interval?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was doing some topology homework and used this equivalence to complete a problem, only I'm not completely sure it actually holds. My intuition tells me it's true, but I can't prove it. If it helps, I haven't taken a real analysis course yet.

Some confirmation or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you all of you. I can't believe I didn't think of the irrational numbers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:** The irrational numbers...

Answer (score 2):

Try reading about [Cantor's set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Answer (score 2):

What is the complement of the rationals?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is not countable